# Is self captured within a nested function

Tags: swift, memory-management, weak-references, nested-function, capture-list

With closures I usually append `[weak self]` onto my capture list and then do a null check on `self`:

```
func myInstanceMethod()
{
    let myClosure =
    {
       [weak self] (result : Bool) in
       if let this = self
       { 
           this.anotherInstanceMethod()
       }
    }   

    functionExpectingClosure(myClosure)
}
```

How do I perform the null check on `self` if I'm using a nested function in lieu of a closure (or is the check even necessary...or is it even good practice to use a nested function like this) i.e.

```
func myInstanceMethod()
{
    func nestedFunction(result : Bool)
    {
        anotherInstanceMethod()
    }

    functionExpectingClosure(nestedFunction)
}
```

Comment: Learning from the rintaro's answer I wrote a more robust answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41984023/5175709)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unfortunately, only Closures have "Capture List" feature like `[weak self]`. For nested functions, You have to use normal `weak` or `unowned` variables.

```
func myInstanceMethod() {
    weak var _self = self
    func nestedFunction(result : Bool) {
        _self?.anotherInstanceMethod()
    }

    functionExpectingClosure(nestedFunction)
}
```

Comment: Is this in official documentation by any chance?

Comment: Seems this is true. I did a test and the weak from the closure is not passed into the self in the nested function. So much for clean code.

Comment: Does not seem to be the case anymore.

Answer (score -4):

Does not seem to be the case anymore. This is valid in swift 4.1:

```
class Foo {
    var increment = 0
    func bar() {
        func method1() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                method2()
            })
        }

        func method2() {
            otherMethod()
            increment += 1
        }
        method1()
    }

    func otherMethod() {

    }
}
```

The question remains: How is `self` captured ?

Comment: If by "valid" you mean that `self` is not strongly captured then I can't approve that. In my case I had a closure and I was calling a nested `func`  from within this closure and the class would not be released, i.e. `deinit` was not called. At least that's what my research/debugging showed me.

Comment: it will be capture strongly here